# Why does BMI088 have 4 interrupt pins?

Tags: gpio-external-interrupt

BMI088 has 4 interrupt pins, 2 for ACC, 2 for GYRO. I've been scanning through the datasheet and can't seem to understand:

1. Why does ACC/Gyro have 2 interrupt pins that do the same thing?
2. INT1~INT4 can be configured as input or output - what do those pins do if configured as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The two pins dont have to do the same thing. The datasheet shows there are two types of interrupts supported on this chip. A new data interrupt (page 18) and a fifo interrupt (page 19) for both the gyro and accelerometer. The datasheet explains the difference of the two but I dont really understand the fifo interrupt.

Also, usually with ICs that have configurable pin functions you'll see the same pin function on multiple pins. Depending on how you lay out your board it may be convenient to have that function on one pin vs the other based on where that signal routes. To have that signal be able to originate from multiple places gives you options.

2. On page 22 it says that the interrupt pins (on this page specifically 3 and 4) can be configured as inputs and will no longer act as interrupt pins. i.e they act as just general input pins.

Link to the product page (scroll down to documents for the datasheet) :
https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/motion-sensors/imus/bmi088.html

Edit: had multiple English mistakes

Comment: You mention page 22 - so you may have a link. If so it's useful to provide links to items mentioned. (The OP should, but if he hasn't then it's useful iof others do). Most people have no idea of what a BMI088 is -  a link helps people learn and also allows people who do know to access the data much more easily.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer to address this

Comment: Answer 1 make sense to me, good explaination! I found the answer to question 2 in the datasheet: "4.9.3.1.3 FIFO synchronization with external interrupts (tag application) for the accel
If the INT1 and/or INT2 pin is configured as input pin (by setting int2_io in register INT2_IO_CTRL 
and/or setting int1_io in register INT1_IO_CTRL), signals on these pins can also be recorded in the 
FIFO, and the frames are “tagged” accordingly. Therefore the pins need to be activated for FIFO 
recording in register FIFO_CONFIG_1 (see 5.3.15)"  I guess should  have read the datasheet more thoroughly.